# Импорт в python, в чём смысл писать "import uuid as uuid"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Недавно начал работу с новым проектом и увидел там такой импорт:

```
import uuid as uuid
```

Вопрос: в чём смысл, если можно сделать обычный import:

```
import uuid
```

Программист который писал, шарит что делает (судя по коду проекта, который мне достался после него).

Comment: Удали `as uuid` и запусти юнит тесты.

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но их нет :D

Comment: Прошу прощения за ответ (удаленный) - я невнимательно прочитал вопрос - думал у вас используется `from uuid import uuid`... В `import uuid as uuid` - никакого смысла я не вижу - зачем давать `alias` полностью совпадающий с оригинальным именем модуля??

Answer (score 2):

ИМХО `import uuid as uuid` - это бессмысленная конструкция.

Доказывает это:

```
import uuid
import uuid as new_uuid

assert uuid == new_uuid
```

Возможно там было: `from uuid import uuid1 as uuid`, а потом это неудачно исправили. Все ошибаются.

Comment: Конструкция бессмысленная, не буду спорить, но что именно доказывает Ваш пример? Ведь модуль не импортируется второй раз, берётся его кэшированный объект. Естественно, что 2 ссылки на один и тот же объект равны. Зачем вообще тогда проводить такое сравнение?

Comment: @nomnoms12, Если бы это были разные сущности, импортировалось бы. Но сущность одна и второго импорта действительно не будет. Если `as` оказывало бы влияние, сущность изменилась бы. Но `as` никакого влияния не оказывает.  В результате мы имеем 2 ссылки прилинкованные к одному объекту, откуда и когда он появился в памяти - не имеет значения. Думаю, что бессмысленно обсуждать, что было бы, если бы...